# Does "all points rational" imply "constant" for this  "cubic" curve over an arbitrary field?

Tags: fields, nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an arbitrary field with a subfield $\mathbb{F}$ of index 2. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{K}[X]$ be univariate non-vanishing polynomials over $\mathbb{K}$ of degree $\leq 3$ each. **Edit: Due to how this problem arises, one may assume that $a,b$ have no common zeros and at least one has degree exactly 3. However, I am also interested in what happens without this extra assumption, but instead the assumption that $char\mathbb{K}\neq2$. The latter to avoid the counterexamples described in the comments.**

Consider the set of points $T:=\{(a(x),b(x)) \mid x\in\mathbb{K}\}$, a subset of $\mathbb{K}^2$.

Prove (or give a counterexample) for the following:

> Claim: Assume every point $T$ is projectively equivalent to a point in $\mathbb{F}\times\mathbb{F}$ (i.e. for every $x\in\mathbb{K}$ we have $a(x)=b(x)\cdot f_x$ for some $f_x\in\mathbb{F}$). Then either $\lvert\mathbb{K}\rvert=4$ or 9, or all points in $T$ are projectively equivalent (that is, $T$ is contained in a one-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-subspace of $\mathbb{K}^2$); put another way, $a/b$ is a constant.

Since we assumed $a,b$ to have no common zeros, we can think of this in terms of projective coordinates. Then the question becomes: If all points on the curve $T$ are $\mathbb{F}$-rational, does this imply that $T$ consists of a single point?

For finite fields, this can be shown using a simple counting argument (had to check the field with 9 elements manually, and found an exception over the field with four elements). It is also not hard to see that the condition of the claim implies that $a,b$ must have coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$.

For $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ I have an argument involving the topology and metric of these fields. For the general case, I tried various approaches, and one of them might still work out (but all my ideas seem at some point to end up in heavy, uninsightful and simply ugly computations)...

But I keep wondering if this isn't a problem that somebody with a better background in number theory or algebraic geometry or something like that could quickly solve with "standard" methods.... so before I keep going on with my little knowledge, I though it best to ask here for any pointer or even solutions :).

---

Lastly, here is one thing I was trying, but couldn't quite complete. It's quite possibly a dead end, so you may not want to get yourself overly distracted by it :): Pick $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}\setminus\mathbb{F}$. For each $t\in\mathbb{K}$, define a polynomial $p_t(x):=a(x+t)b(\alpha+t)-a(\alpha+t) b(x+t)$. They all have $\alpha$ as a zero. And (up to some rescaling), the coefficients of $p_t$ are in $\mathbb{F}$ by hypothesis.

Now if any of the $p_t$ vanishes everywhere, then all do, and $a/b$ is constant. So assume the $p_t$ do not vanish. Then every $p_t$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and so has degree 2 or 3. Indeed, looking at the coefficients, for at most three $t$ can $p_t$ have degree 2, so for almost all it has degree 3, and is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. This sounds quite improbable to me (but that proves nothing, only that I lack imagination ;). So we could now compare several of the $p_t$, and try to derive a contradiction, but this (at least in the naive ways I tried) quickly gets very messy, uninsightful and ugly ;).

Comment: For $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}$ try to show that no non-constant function $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \{ p_1, ... p_n \} \to \mathbb{R}$ can be holomorphic. 

Comment: More generally, for $K$ algebraically closed it's obvious that $a(x) = b(x) f$ has a root in $K$ for all but at most one $f \in K$. 

Comment: Here's a sketch of my metric argument for $\mathbb{C,R}$: Consider $T$ as subset of the vectorspace $K^2$. The hypothesis now is that $T$ is contained in the union $S$ of all 1-dimensional subspaces / rays with ``real slope''. Pick $x$ such that $p_1:=p(x):=(a(x),b(x))$ is far from 0. Then $p_1$ and $p_2:=p(x+\epsilon)$ are connected by a path in $T$ which doesn't contain 0. But in $S$, all paths between points are either in a ray, or they pass through 0 and are in two rays. Since the curve crosses 0 at most 3 times, it is in the union of finitely many $S$-rays. Then it is in only one ray.

Comment: If $\mathbb{K}$ is a non-perfect field of characteristic two, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{K}^2$, then $a(x)=1,b(x)=x^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: You need a separability assumption or else there are counterexamples in characteristic 2. Let $a(x)=x^2$, $b(x)=1$, and consider an inseparable quadratic extension e.g. $k(t)/k(t^2)$ with char(k)=2.

Comment: @Qiaochu: So what you are saying is that $f:=a/b$ as function from $K\to K$ is either constant, or ``almost'' surjective if $K$ is algebraically closed. That is, its image is dense in $K$ in the Zariski topology -- i.e. $f$ is a dominant rational mapping. True enough, that's a very nice and simple argument to solve the algebraically closed case. Thanks :).

Now, can this be extended to the general case somehow?

Comment: Thanks, I should have expected that characteristic 2 will produce counterexamples, it always does for me ;). However, I have to exclude characteristic 2 for other reasons anyway, so I am not overly concerned. It is very good to have concrete counterexamples for this, though. Thanks again!

Comment: Darn Felipe, curse my slow typing :-)

Comment: @Kevin: Great minds think alike and fools seldom differ...

Comment: By the way: I can probably also add the assumption that $a$ has degree exactly $3$. That rules out the counterexamples by Felipe and Kevin, but I wonder if there are others then (in characteristic 2) ?

Comment: If you assume that $a$ has degree exactly three then the statement "we may assume that they have no common zero" becomes false. Is that still an assumption, or can I just say $a(x)=x^3$ and $b(x)=x$ and same counterexample? Your question is the following: you have a morphism $f:P^1\to P^1$ defined over $K$, either constant or of degree at most 3, and it maps $P^1(K)$ into $P^1(F)$, and you want to prove it's constant. I am wondering now whether you're furthermore demanding that the morphism have degree exactly 3.

Comment: With "we may assume that they have no common zero" I meant that "due to the way these polynomials turn up, we can arrange things so that they have no common zero". I'll try to clarify the question accordingly.

In addition, I can arrange it so that the degree of $a$ (or $b$) is exactly 3; not sure whether I can force this simultaneously, need to think about that.

However, this requires lengthy technical arguments. So, I am also still interested in the original question (degree of a and b $\leq 3$), under the additional assumption that $char K\neq 2$, if that is not much harder to handle.

Comment: If one has degree exactly 3 then you can make the other one have degree exactly three by e.g. taking the reciprocal if necessary, and adding 1 if necessary. Similarly if both have degree 3 you can lower the degree of one of them. The degree of $a/b$ as a rational function is just the max of the degrees. I don't know if it helps, but perhaps the theory of "thin sets" etc in Serre's lectures on the Mordell-Weil theorem would show that the map had to be constant in the case that $K$ and $F$ are number fields.

Comment: [PS is your full name Apple Max?]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the degree. Makes sense.

And no, my full name is not Apple Max ;) (if you actually want to know it, you can find out on my homepage, linked from the user profile).

Comment: [it was your little 'logo', whatever they're called, that made me ask]

Comment: Back to the point, can you explain the reasoning behind your assertion "It is also not hard to see that the condition of the claim implies that $a,b$ must have coefficients in $F$" in the original question? I asked a more general question, using a more geometric language, at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67304/image-of-projective-1-space-contained-in-projective-1-space-over-a-smaller-field . Yours is a special case of this.

Comment: The idea is to exploit that $x^i$ and $x^j$ are linearly independent for $i\neq j$, and use that to describe the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$ of $a$ resp. $b$ in terms of elements of these:
  For all $x\in K$ (ignoring zeros of $b$ for the moment) we have by our hypothesis that $a(x)=b(x) c_x$, where $c_x\in F$. For $x\in F$, this gives a linear equation with $a_i,b_j$ as variables (!) and with the $x^i$ and $c_x$ as coefficients in $F$. Doing this for eight $x\in F$, we find the $a_i$, $b_j$ as the solution of a system of $F$-linear equations. 

Comment: This requires that $q:=\lvert F \rvert$ is at least 8. For the remaining cases $q=2,3,4,5,7$, one can use other tools. E.g. I just fired up GAP and verified the claim there. For $q=2,3$ there are counterexamples.
 Oops, I previously claimed that there is no counterexample for $q=3$, but obviously there is: In a field with $q^2$ elements, of course $x+x^q$ and $x^{q+1}$ are in the subfield with $q$ elements, and so we get $a(x)=x^q+x$, $b(x)=1$ for $q=2,3$ as counterexamples. But no others.

Comment: Max: I'm just writing this comment because I know the system will alert you to it -- I just wanted to point out that currently there are two answers for my more general question, and both of these should resolve your question too, at least in the separable case when the base is infinite.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look.

Since I am just interested in the case where $F$ has index $2$ in $K$, then unless the characteristic is 2 I am in the separable case anyway, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an answer but I think it's progress. It started off by thinking of restriction of scalars but I've translated it down to a rather more mundane point of view.

Let me call the fields $K$ and $F$ to save some typing.

Let me first deal with the finite field case. My understanding of the question as it currently stands is that we have a morphism $t:\mathbf{P}^1_K\to\mathbf{P}^1_K$ of degree exactly 3, with the property that the image of $\mathbf{P}^1(K)$ is contained within $\mathbf{P}^1(F)$ and we want to show that $F$ has size 2.

The case $F$ finite is easy to deal with. The pre-image of an $F$-point has size at most 3, so if $q$ is the size of $F$ then $q^2+1\leq 3(q+1)$ and we quickly deduce $q\leq 3$ and we deal with the case $q=3$ by hand.

Now for the case $F$ infinite. My understanding is that we can assume that the characteristic isn't 2. So we can write $K=F(\sqrt{d})$ for some $d\in F$, not a square. Let me now think of $K$ as a 2-dimensional vector space over $F$ with basis $[1,\sqrt{d}]$ and let's translate the question into a messy algebra one.

We see $a(x+y\sqrt{d})=L+M\sqrt{d}$, where $L$ and $M$ are $F$-linear combinations of the six polynomials $x$, $y$ [real and imag parts of $x+y\sqrt{d}$], $x^2+dy^2, 2xy$ [this comes from $(x+y\sqrt{d})^2$ and $x^3+3dxy^2, dy^3+3x^2y$. Similarly $b(x+y\sqrt{d})=N+P\sqrt{d}$.

We are given that for all $x,y\in F$ we have $L(x,y)+M(x,y)\sqrt{d}=f(x,y)(N(x,y)+P(x,y)\sqrt{d})$ with $f(x,y)\in F$ (forget the finitely many points where $f$ has a pole), and we deduce that $L(x,y)P(x,y)=M(x,y)N(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in F$. But $F$ is infinite and this implies that, as polynomials in $x$ and $y$, we have $LP=MN$ *identically*. This is a piece of information that wasn't clear before.

This means that we can base change our entire situation to the algebraic closure, and replace $F$ with $\overline{F}$ and $K$ with $\overline{F}\oplus\overline{F}$, and (calling these new rings $F$ and $K$) we now have maps $\mathbf{P}^1_K\to\mathbf{P}^1_K$ which are defined over $K$ and such that the image of $\mathbf{P}^1(K)$ is in $\mathbf{P}^1(F)$. 
[Note: it's at this point that I'm assuming $K/F$ separable.]. Now I want to say "and now we should be done because of alg geom" but in fact what I mean is "and now someone else will have to take over because I have to clear up the kitchen".

Comment: Over the algebraic closure it seems like I have something like a rational map from affine 2-space to affine 2-space, of the form $(s,t)\mapsto (g(s),h(t))$ (this is the statement that the map is defined over $K$), and whose image is contained in a diagonal affine 1-space. This means each horizontal line and each vertical line must be mapped to a point, and this means that the image of all of affine 2-space must be a point. Am I now done? 

Comment: In your answer, everything up to the final paragraph seems clear. But why exactly does $LP=MN$ imply you can change the setting as described? You somehow seem to arrive at the conclusion that the curve $(a(x,y),b(x,y))$ in the old $K$ (where multiplication "mixes" real and imaginary parts) can be ``untangled'' to $(g(x),h(y))$ and we can thus switch to $\overline F\oplus\overline F$. Since you mention it so casually, it's probably something terribly basic. But I don't see how it follows. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Accepting this as a black box for the moment, the rest seems clear, assuming new-$F$ maps diagonally into new-$K$. Indeed, can't we then immediately conclude $g=h$?

Comment: Max -- I just raced down some comments. I'm not saying I've answered the question -- I hoped someone could either take over or point out a problem. If $K=F(\sqrt{d})$ then the moment I adjoin another $\sqrt{d}$ to the situation I can unravel everything. $LP=MN$ guarantees that I don't lose control at this point. That's the proof plan anyway.