# Image of projective 1-space contained in projective 1-space over a smaller field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is inspired by

[Does "all points rational" imply "constant" for this  "cubic" curve over an arbitrary field?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67126/does-all-points-rational-imply-constant-for-this-cubic-curve-over-an-arbit) .

Say $K/F$ is a finite separable extension of fields. Assume $F$ is infinite (or else there are trivial counterexamples to the question below). Say

$$t:\mathbf{P}^1_K\to\mathbf{P}^1_K$$

is a non-constant morphism defined over $K$, with the property that

$$t(\mathbf{P}^1(K))\subseteq\mathbf{P}^1(F).$$

Does this imply that $K=F$?

Comments: (1) the question linked to above is a special case of this, written in a slightly more hands-on way. (2) There are counterexamples in the inseparable case of the form $t(x)=x^p$ with $K/F$ purely inseparable of degree $p$. (3) If $K$ is algebraically closed then $F=K$ trivially because $t$ is surjective on points. (4) If $F$ is a number field then I guess one can use the theory of "thin sets" (the ideas used in the proof of Hilbert irreducibility) to prove that $F=K$. (5) If you generalise to other projective curves then again the result fails, because e.g. the curves could have no $K$-points at all and $t$ could be the identity. (6) On the other hand one could ask about projective $n$-space or even affine 1-space -- one just needs a lot of $K$-points to make the question interesting...

Comment: To me, (4) seems most significant: it seems that one should look to easy examples of non-Hilbertian fields for counterexamples.  E.g. what happens over $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: I also took the liberty of adding the (new!) tag field-arithmetic.  This is kind of based on a hunch, but I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Isn't it the case that $t$ is automatically defined over $F$ ? (at least if $t$ is a polynomial, by interpolation). If so I have an argument (I think) for polynomials, but I'm not sure whether it extends for rational functions.

Comment: Francois -- in the original question I linked to, the questioner makes this assertion, but I couldn't see it (I'm not saying it's false, I just didn't see the argument). The questioner seemed to have thought seriously about his variant though so it wouldn't surprise me if it were true.

Comment: Pete: field arithmetic sounds just right. I almost chose "arithmetic geometry" but for me that's alg geom over a 'field of interest to number theorists' (perhaps a 'field of arithmetic interest'), rather than over an arbitrary field that happens not to be alg closed. But this question has as special cases things like "prove that if $K/F$ is of degree bigger than 1 and separable then $\{k^2:k\in K\}$ can't be a subset of $F$" and that sounds like field arithmetic to me!

Comment: Francois -- what is your argument for polynomials defined over $F$?

Comment: PS sorry I'm not in Lyon now :-(

Comment: Yes, $t$ must be defined over $F$: We can assume $K/F$ is Galois; then, for all automorphisms $g$ of $K/F$, $gtg^{-1}\vert_{\mathbf{P}(F)}=t\vert_{\mathbf{P}(F)}$. This shows that $gtg^{-1}=t$, and we conclude by Galois descent.

Comment: [Btw, what's the etiquette about deleted comments; should I acknowledge them, thereby adding to the comment clutter as I'm doing here? (Sorry!)]

Comment: @Kevin : There is a talk right now but here is a sketch of the argument : let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be a basis of $K/F$ and consider the polynomial $P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=t(a_1 X_1+\ldots+a_n X_n)$. It takes $F^n$ to $F$ so by interpolation, we have $P \in F[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$. By homogeneity we must have $(a_1 X_1+\ldots+a_n X_n)^m \in F[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ for some $m \geq 1$, and this is not too hard to conclude $n=1$, so $K=F$.

Comment: The polynomial interpolation argument by François is essentially what I had in mind in my original question (the one Kevin links to at the start of this question). It requires the ground field to be sufficiently large, but since here $F$ is assumed to be infinite, that is no problem of course.

Comment: Dear Keerthi, Why can you assume that $K/F$ is Galois? Couldn't it happen that after extending to the Galois closure of $K$, the condition that
the image of $t$ is contained in the $F$-points no longer holds?  Regards, Matt

Comment: Dear Matt--I hope I have this correct. It seems like we only need $t(\mathbf{P}(F))\subset\mathbf{P}(F)$, which is certainly valid after base change from $K$ to its Galois closure.

Comment: An easy comment: The claim is true for polynomial maps in characteristic zero. Proof: Let $t(x) = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k t^k$ with $a_d \neq 0$. For any $f: F \to F$, set $(\Delta f)(x) = f(x+1)-f(x)$. Then $(\Delta^{d-1} t)(x) = d! a_k x + b$ for some constant $b$. We see that, for any $x \in K$, the quantity $d! a_k x+b$ is in $F$. Plugging in $x=0$ and $x=1$, we have $b \in F$ and $d! a_k \in F$. So $x \in K$ implies $((d! a_k x+b)-b)/(d! a_k)$ is in $F$; that is to say, $x \in F$. (We used characteristic zero to make sure that $d! a_k$ is nonzero.)

Comment: David's argument makes me realize that I also assume characteristic 0 (in the last step of my argument). I don't know what happens with a separable extension in char. $p$.

Comment: I wonder if the following version of Francois's argument works: Assume $K/F$ is Galois, consider the map (a linear projection) $p:\mathbf{A}^n_K\to\mathbf{A}^1_K$ constructed from the basis $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ for $K$ over $F$; we will assume also that $a_1=1$. It's enough to show that this is Galois-equivariant (note that $p$ takes the standard co-ordinate vectors to the chosen basis of $K$). Consider $t\circ p:\mathbf{A}^n_K\to\mathbf{P}^1_K$: this is defined over $F$. Using the fact that $t$ is also defined over $F$, for any automorphism $g$ of $K/F$, we have $t\circ p\circ g=t\circ p$. 

Comment: So the pair $(p,g^{-1}\circ p\circ g)$ defines a map $f:\mathbf{A}^n_K\to Z$, where $Z$ is the self-fiber product of $\mathbf{P}^1_K$ over $\mathbf{P}^1_K$ via $t$. $Z$ is a curve: it has a bunch of irreducible components, as many as the degree of $t$, and the diagonal is one such component. The image of $f$ lies in one of these components, but the restriction of $f$ to the first co-ordinate axis in $\mathbf{A}^n_K$ has its image in the diagonal, and so all of $f$ should land in the diagonal as well. In other words, $p=g^{-1}\circ p\circ g$, and so $p$ is Galois-equivariant.

Comment: "Using the fact that $t$ is also defined over $F$, for any automorphism $g$ of $K/F$, we have $t\circ p\circ g=t\circ p$." This should be $t\circ g^{-1}\circ p\circ g=t\circ p$.



Comment: @Keerthi : I don't follow, why should $p$ be Galois-equivariant (note that $p(\mathbf{A}^n(F)) \not\subset \mathbf{A}^1(F)$) ? Anyway, if $K/F$ is Galois (without assuming char. 0), taking a normal basis $(\sigma(\alpha))_{\sigma \in G}$, it is not too hard to show directly that the polynomial $(\sum_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(\alpha) T_\sigma)^m$ doesn't have coeffs in $F$, so the result is also true in the case $K/F$ is Galois.

Comment: Dear Francois--If $K=F$ then $p$ must trivially be Galois equivariant, so if the result is true, then the Galois equivariance of $p$ should also hold. Also, if $K/F$ is not Galois, we can define $p$ over $K$, and check its Gslois equivariance over the Galois closure of $K$. Which part of the argument seems fishy to you?

Comment: Dear Keerthi, very nice! Your argument seems correct to me and it also seems to work in the case where $K/F$ is not Galois, I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This proof was inspired by an idea of Francois Brunault and appears piecemeal in the comments to the question; it's probably not materially different from David's proof. Choose some $F$-basis $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ for $K$ with $a_1=1$, and let $p:\mathbf{A}^n_K\to\mathbf{A}^1_K$ be the map $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)\mapsto \sum_ia_iX_i$.

**Lemma** Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are varieties over a field $F$ such that $X(F)$ is dense in $X$, that $K/F$ is a separable extension and that $f:X_K\to Y_K$ is a morphism such that $f(X(F))\subset Y(F)$. Then $f$ is defined over $F$.

**Proof:** Indeed, we can replace $K$ by its Galois closure and assume that $K/F$ is Galois. For every automorphism $g$ of $K/F$, $gfg^{-1}\vert_{X(F)}=f\vert_{X(F)}$; since $X(F)$ is dense in $X$, this implies that $gfg^{-1}=f$, and we conclude by Galois descent.

**Corollary 1** $t$ is defined over $F$.

**Corollary 2** $t\circ p$ is defined over $F$.

Let $L/F$ be the Galois closure of $K/F$.

**Claim** The base changed map $p:\mathbf{A}^n_L\to\mathbf{A}^1_L$ is Galois-equivariant.

**End of proof assuming claim:** For any automorphism $g$ of $L/F$ and any $1\leq i\leq n$, $$ga_i=g(p(e_i))=p(g(e_i)=p(e_i)=a_i,$$ 
where $e_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ standard basis vector for $\mathbf{A}^n_L$. So all the $a_i$ lie in $F$ (and, in particular, $n=1$).

**Proof of claim:** For any automorphism $g$ of $L/F$, we have
$$t\circ p=g(t\circ p)g^{-1}=gtg^{-1}\circ gpg^{-1}=t\circ gpg^{-1}.$$
So the pair $(p,gpg^{-1})$ defines a map $f:\mathbf{A}^n_L\to Z_L$, where $Z$ is the self fiber-product of $\mathbf{P}^1_F$ over $\mathbf{P}^1_F$ via $t$. $Z$ is a curve (not necessarily reduced or irreducible), and $f$ maps onto an irreducible component of $Z$. One of the irreducible components of $Z$ is the diagonal $\Delta$. Showing that $p=gpg^{-1}$ amounts to showing that $f$ maps onto $\Delta$. But $f$ maps the $F$-points of the first co-ordinate axis of $\mathbf{A}^n$ into the diagonal:
$$f(x,0,\ldots,0)=(x,gx)=(x,x),$$
for all $x\in\mathbf{A}^1(F)$. So it must map all of $\mathbf{A}^n_K$ into the diagonal, and we are done.

EDIT: Here is one way to view this proof in a more general framework. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map of $F$-varieties, with $X$ non-empty. Suppose that:

1. $f$ is finite.
2. $f(X(K))\subset Y(F)$.
3. $X(F)$ is dense in $X$.

We also suppose that the Weil restriction $X'=\text{Res}_{K/F}X_K$ is representable. Let $p:X'_K\to X_K$ be the natural adjunction map. The hypotheses imply (see Lemma above) that both $f$ and $f\circ p$ are defined over $F$. The same proof as in the claim above shows that $p$ is also defined over $F$. This shows that $K=F$.

Comment: That looks pretty different to me! You never use the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1_K$ has a lot of endomorphisms, which is pretty crucial for me. I think your argument should generalize to other maps $X \to Y$ with $X(F)$ infinite much better than mine.

Comment: So I get home from work and find I have two proofs to choose from :-/ Which one do I accept?? 

Comment: Is the Weil restriction ever not representable? 

Comment: The best statement I can find is in Bosch, et. al.'s 'Neron models', Theorem 4 on p. 194, which implies that the Weil restriction of anything quasi-projective is representable (it's the same issue as with existence of quotients by finite groups). There are probably some pathological beasts hidden somewhere in the work of Raynaud. In any case, we can probably get away in this case with requiring $X'$ to be something like the stack quotient of a scheme by a finite group, which is fine.

Comment: Actually, even that is not necessary, since we only need $X'$ to be representable over some Galois extension of $K$, and this is obviously the case.

Comment: I think that this proof is a generalisation + details of the idea I sketched in the original question. I was hazy about the details and wasn't sure whether it would work. Typos: In "end of proof assuming claim" you imply $a_i=p(X_i)$ but you mean $a_i=p(e_i)$ with $e_i$ the vector $(0,0,..,1,..,0)$. And your pair $(p,gpg^{-1})$ gives a map defined over $L$ not $K$ I think. I am surprised that there are problems with glueing in Weil restriction! I can see the problems with quotients by finite groups but with Weil restriction you have the glue already...

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I accepted your proof but this was just a random choice; I could have accepted David's. Both proofs have their merits.

Comment: Kevin--Thanks for the corrections. I guess I should also thank the coin you were using! As for the Weil restriction, at least in the case where the field extension is separable, it is just a special case of the construction of quotients by finite group actions, so the same kinds of issues arise (you need every finite collection of points to be contained in an affine, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this proof seems quite nice and settles my original problem (from the question Kevin linked at the start of his question). But I am stuck at one point in trying to understand it: You say that the diagonal is one of the irreducible components of $Z$. But why? I mean, it is clear that it is irreducible, by why can't it be contained in an even bigger component? Since you mention it so casually, I guess it's something obvious to algebraic geometers, but it isn't for me. Any hints / reference I could look at? Thanks :)

Comment: Max--This is where we use the finiteness of $t$ (or $f$ in the more general statement). The point is that every component of $Z$ has dimension $1$, and so each component is a curve. The diagonal is obviously a curve inside $Z$, and you can't have a curve be a proper sub-variety of another curve (any non-trivial equation will cut out only finitely many points). In general, every component of $Z$ will have dimension equal to $dim X$, and a similar statement holds: no variety can have a proper sub-variety of the same dimension, and in particular, the diagonal will be a component.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a proof. Let $t$, $K$ and $F$ be as stated.

**Preliminary reduction:** $t$ is defined over $F$.

**Proof:** Let $t(x) = p(x)/q(x)$, with $p=\sum_{i=0}^r p_i x^i$ and $q=\sum_{j=0}^s q_j x^j$. For every $x \in F$, let $y = t(x)$; then $\sum q_j x^j y - \sum p_i x^i$ is a linear constraint on the $p_i$ and $q_j$, with coefficients in $F$. Since there is a nonzero solution to these constraints in $K$, there is also a solution in $F$; call it $(p'_0, \ldots, p'_r, q'_0, \ldots, q'_s)$. So we have a rational function $p'/q'$ such that $p'(x)/q'(x) = p(x)/q(x)$ for all $x \in F$. Since $F$ is infinite, this means that $p/q = p'/q'$. QED

**Theorem:** Let $F$ be infinite. Let $t \in F(x)$ be nonconstant and separable. Let $L$ be the subfield of $F(x)$ generated by $t(g(x))$, as $g$ ranges over all nonconstant rational functions in $F(x)$. Then $L=F(x)$.

**Proof:** Since $F(t) \subseteq L \subseteq F(x)$, we see that $F(x)/L$ is a separable finite extension. By Luroth's theorem, $L = F(u)$ for some $u \in F(x)$, and this $u$ is a separable map $\mathbb{P}^1_F \to \mathbb{P}^1_F$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $u$ has degree $d>1$.

Since $F$ is infinite, we can find two points in $\mathbb{P}^1_F$ where $t$ takes two different values; using an automorphism of $\mathbb{P}^1_F$, we may assume that $t(\infty) \neq t(0)$.

Since $u$ is separable, for all but finitely many $y \in \mathbb{P}^1_F$, the preimage $u^{-1}(y)$ in $F^{\mathrm{alg}}$ has size $d$. Since $F$ is infinite, we can choose $\zeta \in \mathbb{P}^1_F$ so that $u^{-1}(u(\zeta))$ has size $d$ (with the preimage taken in  $F^{\mathrm{alg}}$.)

Let $\alpha$ be an element of $u^{-1}(u(\zeta))$ other than $\zeta$. So $\alpha$ lies in some finite extension of $F$ (possibly $F$ itself). Let $p$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and set $g(x) = p(x)/(x-\zeta)$. So $(t \circ g)(\alpha) = t(0) \neq t(\infty) = (t \circ g)(\zeta)$. So $t \circ g$ takes different values on $\alpha$ and on $\zeta$, and thus cannot be in $F(u)$. We have found an element of $L$ which is not in $F(u)$, a contradiction. The theorem is proved. QED

By the Theorem, $x$ can be written as $h(t \circ g_1, t \circ g_2, \ldots, t \circ g_N)$ for some rational functions $g_i \in F(x)$ and some $h \in F(y_1, \ldots, y_N)$. So, for any $x \in K$, we have 
$$x = h(t(g_1(x)), \ldots, t(g_N(x)) ).$$

Now, all of the $g_i(x)$ are in $K$. So, by hypothesis, all the $t(g_i(x))$ are in $F$. So $h(t(g_1(x)), \ldots, t(g_N(x)) )$ is in $F$. In short, we have shown that, for every $x \in K$, we have $x \in F$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: David -- I wonder to what extent Luroth is necessary. It had occurred to me that Luroth might be relevant -- this is one of the reasons I mentioned projective $n$-space in the question. Thanks for the answer. I've not read it yet (or Keerthi's) so I'll refrain from accepting anything.

Comment: It isn't actually. I thought about explaining this, but I decided my answer was already too long. What I really need to know is that $L$ is the fraction field of some curve $Y$ over $F$, and that I get a separable map $u: \mathbb{P}^1_F \to Y$. The fact that $Y \cong \mathbb{P}^1_F$ isn't necessary, it just makes the argument much more readable. I think I wrote the above in such a way that it works unaltered with the weaker level of knowledge about the target of $u$.

Comment: OK I finally read it. This seems fine to me. You seem to assume $t$ separable though.

Comment: PS thanks! This question was bugging me :-)

Comment: OK so finally the impossible problem of which of two distinct correct proofs to accept. I tossed a coin and Keerthi won. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: You're right, I am assuming $t$ separable. On the other hand, I'm not assuming $K/F$ separable. I lost track of which was one I was supposed to assume.